# android prevent part of the map on screen from dragging

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I have map fragment inside of the frame layout, and i want to disable it from dragging when i will be using another containter(e.g relative layout) on top of it, which will contains seekbar and some textViews.

I don't want to map drag when i accidently touch some area in my container and not the item inside of it. Is there a way to do this? How to disable that part of map on screen?

My layout example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/maps_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.app.activity.MapsActivity"></fragment>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <com.example.app.ui.views.CustomRelativeLayoutContainer
                android:id="@+id/mainMapSlider"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"></com.example.app.ui.views.CustomRelativeLayoutContainer>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/addSeekBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
                map:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_history" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make your `RelativeLayout` clickable adding this:

```
android:clickable="true"
```