# How to implement Bottom sheet on top google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, bottom-sheet

I am trying to display a bottom sheet filling only a third of the screen width above a map that fills the whole screen.(I want the user to be able to move around the map while the bottom sheet it's displayed)

When the bottom sheet it's shown it has a peek height of 300dp, but ideally the user could make it grow to the top of the screen.

The problem is that **I am not able to drag the bottom sheet when the map is displayed**.

This is the layout of the activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blanco">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        ....
        ...

    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/altura_infos_mapa">


        .....
        .....

        <LinearLayout>

            <se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
                android:id="@+id/ListaCentros"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
            </se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried to hide the map and I am able to drag the bottom sheet which means that somehow the scroll of the bottom sheet is in conflict with the map.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

[image: This is a screen shot of the bottom sheet displayed on top of the map]

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316591/android-prevent-part-of-the-map-on-screen-from-dragging/43316638#43316638

Comment: I have tried that too but it doesn't work either